# Powershell variable expansion in single quoted string

Tags: json, powershell, single-quotes, variable-expansion

I need to build a JSON variable that contains another JSON formatted content which should be formatted as a string. I'm putting the inner JSON into single quote so it wont get parsed along with the outer JSON. The inner JSON contains a variable that should be extended. Unfortunately, the single quotes prevent this.
Example:

```
$link = "http://www.google.de"
$event = @{
   var1 = "sys"
   var2 = "yadda"
   inner_json = '"System": {"link":"$link"}}'
}
$json = $event | ConvertTo-Json
```

The variable $inner_json must be embedded as a string.
Is there any way to enforce the expansion of $link within the single quotes? Any other idea how to solve this problem? Any help is apprectiated.
edit: I would be expecting the inner_json like this:

```
{"var1":"sys", "var2":"yadda", "inner_json": "{\"System\": {\"link\":\"google.de\"}}"}
```

Comment: Can you post the json you're expecting from your example ```$event | ConvertTo-Json```? You can possibly solve this by using nested hashtables, but seeing your desired json would make sure...

Comment: `$inner_json = """System"": {""link"":""$($link)""}}"`

Comment: I would be expecting: {"var1":"sys", "var2":"yadda", "inner_json": "{\"System\": {\"link\":\"http://www.google.de\"}}"}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you prepare the object (using a `HashTable` or `PSCustomObject`), variables (starting with a `$`, including `$var1`, `$inner_json`) will be automatically expanded anyway.
I think you want to do this:

```
$link = "http://www.google.de"
$event = @{
    var1 = 'sys'
    var2 = 'yadda'
    inner_json = @{
        System = @{
            link = $link
        }
    }
}
$event | ConvertTo-Json

{
  "inner_json": {
    "System": {
      "link": "http://www.google.de"
    }
  },
  "var2": "yadda",
  "var1": "sys"
}
```

Based on the added expectation:
<sub>*Note:

Double quotes are automatically escaped with a backslash (`\`) in json.

To escape a double quote in PowerShell, use the backtick: (`` ` ``)</sub>

```
$link = "http://www.google.de"
$event = @{
    var1 = 'sys'
    var2 = 'yadda'
    inner_json = "{`"System`": {`"link`":`"$Link`"}}"
}
$event | ConvertTo-Json

{
  "inner_json": "{\"System\": {\"link\":\"http://www.google.de\"}}",
  "var2": "yadda",
  "var1": "sys"
}
```

But it is better to stay away from fabricating a Json string (including the inner Json string) and also create the inner Json from an object and *literally* embed that string into the outer Json:

```
$link = "http://www.google.de"
$event = @{
    var1 = 'sys'
    var2 = 'yadda'
    inner_json = @{System = @{link = $Link}} | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
}
$event | ConvertTo-Json

{
  "inner_json": "{\"System\":{\"link\":\"http://www.google.de\"}}",
  "var2": "yadda",
  "var1": "sys"
}
```

Comment: Makes sense, but the inner json would be parsed. see my comment above how the outer json should look like

Comment: note that if order of properties is important you can create an OrderedDictionary instead of a hashtable with ```$event = [ordered] @{ ... }```

Comment: Thanks a lot! the convertto-json on the inner_json did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

[iRon's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59820777/45375) contains the best solution for your use case.

---

To answer your question *as suggested by its title*, which is really a different use case:

You can use `$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString()` to interpret verbatim strings as expandable ones *on demand*:

```
# A variable to reference in the template string below.
$link = 'http://example.org'

# A verbatim string that is to be interpreted as an expandable one later, on demand:
$template = '"System": {"link":"$link"}}'

# Expand the template, using the current values of the variables referenced:
$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($template)
```

The above yields a string with the following verbatim content; note how the value of `$link` was expanded:

```
"System": {"link":"http://example.org"}}
```

Comment: This is a more generic usecase and also works as a solution for my issue. Thanks!